# MVC4 regularexpression ignorecase causing problems

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing regular Expression check on submit and when I put ignorcase nothing goes through, for instance this code below has ignorecase and any word I put gets rejected

```
[RegularExpression("^((?!(stupid|www|gamble|http))./*i)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid word")]
```

however if I takeout ignorecase and put the code like this then it works

```
[RegularExpression("^((?!(stupid|www|gamble|http)).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid word")]
```

but without ignorecase someone can easily put Www or WWW and it goes through so my question is; is there anyway I can use ignorecase so that it only affects the words inside the regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/*i` isn't a valid ignore case marker for .NET regular expressions. You want `(?i)` as follows:

```
(?i)^((?!(stupid|www|gamble|http)).)*$
```

In your code:

```
[RegularExpression("(?i)^((?!(stupid|www|gamble|http)).)*$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid word")]
```

You can read about the inline options [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)